# How to make two inputs react to each other in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, reactive-programming

I am building a tool to calculate how much it would cost to buy certain material.
The problem is that sometimes the user buys it either by mass or volume.

I would like a way to have two active inputs (mass and volume) and each automatically updates considering the material density.

I tried computed properties and watchers but couldn't make it work properly.

Here is what I'd like it to look like and what I tried 
https://jsfiddle.net/yfuk958j/

```
  Mass = <input v-model.number="mass"> <br/> 
  Volume = <input v-model.number="volume"><br/>
```

```
  computed: {
    volume() {
      return this.mass * this.density
    },
    mass () { 
    return this.volume / this.density 
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is 2 inputs, each bound to a property of your vm. And a watch function to update any of them when the other changes:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    density: 1,
    mass: 1, 
    volume: 1,
    inputType: 'mass'
  },
  watch: {
    mass(val) {
      this.volume = val/this.density;
    },
    volume(val) {
      this.mass = val*this.density;
    },
    density(val) {
      this.volume = this.mass/val;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    round(val) {
      return Math.round(val * 1e3)/1e3
    }
  }
})
```

```css
span {min-width: 100px; display: inline-block;}
input[type="range"] {width: 200px;}
input[type="number"] {width: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <span>Density:</span> <input v-model="density" type="range" min=".1" max="10" step="0.1">{{density}}g/cm<sup>3</sup>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Mass:</span> <input v-model="mass" type="range" min="1" max="1e4" step="0.001">
      <input v-model="mass" type="number" min="1" step="0.1" max="1e4">g
      [Volume: {{round(volume)}}cm<sup>3</sup>]
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Volume:</span> <input v-model="volume"  type="range" min="2" max="1e4" step="0.001">
      <input v-model="volume"  type="number" min="2" max="1e4" step="0.1">cm<sup>3</sup>
      [Mass: {{round(mass)}}g]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```